# FileNotFoundException, the file exists Java

Tags: java, file-io, mp3, filenotfoundexception, jlayer

I have a very strange issue, I'm trying to play some MP3s with some Java code and JLayer. I have a method setup to generate the file path, but it's giving me a ton of grief. Here is the return statement (and all the code involved in the method):

```
private static String findSoundFile(String numSeq)
{
    return "file:///Users/user/Desktop/FinishedPhone/" + numSeq + ".mp3"
}
```

I have a set of maybe ~150 mp3 files, all named 1.mp3, 2.mp3 etc. They go up to about 156 (there's some missing in between). Based on user input of a 3 digit code, it plays one of the sounds. This code works **flawlessly** for anything between 1-99, its when you get to 100 where it stops working. When the user punches in 100 or 110 or what have you, Java throws a FileNotFoundException. I assure you, the file is there. Here is the code that uses the filepath returned by findSoundFile:

```
public static void processNumberSequence(String numSeq) throws IOException
{
    if (numSeq != "")
    {
        String soundLoc = findSoundFile(numSeq);
        File file = new File(soundLoc);
        System.out.println("System can read: " + file.canRead());
        System.out.println(soundLoc);
        SoundPlayer soundToPlay = new SoundPlayer(soundLoc);
        soundToPlay.play();
    }
}
```

It gets weirder, when I fill in the space that numSeq is supposed to fill in, like this:

```
private static String findSoundFile(String numSeq)
{
    return "file:///Users/user/Desktop/FinishedPhone/110.mp3";
}
```

The above code, works fine, plays the sound without hang up. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated, and please ask if there's any confusion.

The stacktrace:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /Users/user/Desktop/FinishedPhone/111.mp3 (No such file or directory)
at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:120)
at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:79)
at sun.net.www.protocol.file.FileURLConnection.connect(FileURLConnection.java:70)
at sun.net.www.protocol.file.FileURLConnection.getInputStream(FileURLConnection.java:161)
at java.net.URL.openStream(URL.java:1010)
at SoundPlayer.play(SoundPlayer.java:26)
at SerialProcessor.processNumberSequence(SerialProcessor.java:37)
at SerialTest.serialEvent(SerialTest.java:98)
at gnu.io.RXTXPort.sendEvent(RXTXPort.java:732)
at gnu.io.RXTXPort.eventLoop(Native Method)
at gnu.io.RXTXPort$MonitorThread.run(RXTXPort.java:1575)
```

ls -l of one of the files:

```
-rw-r--rw-  1 user  staff  432923 Feb 27 14:15 /Users/user/Desktop/FinishedPhone/111.mp3
```

ls -l for one under 100:

```
-rw-r--rw-  1 user  staff  480570 Feb 25 20:43 /Users/user/Desktop/FinishedPhone/99.mp3
```

Comment: Can you show the stacktrace?

Comment: In findSoundFile(), what do you see when you examine "numSeq" in a debugger or when printing to System.out?

Comment: what do you get if you debug findSoundFile for the value of numSeq when the user inputs 100 or higher?

Comment: @beny23 ill update the post

Comment: Kind out of scope, but ``if (numSeq != "")`` I would recommend to change to ``if (!"".equals(numSeq))``.

Comment: @Yakattak - show us the relevant part of the code where **numSeq** is defined and assigned any values.

Comment: Can you show the output of `ls -l /Users/user/Desktop/FinishedPhone/111.mp3`?

Comment: @Fred: or even better `!"".equals(numSeq)`, can't trip over a `null` `numSeq`...

Comment: Under the debugger, numSeq is "111"., @Fred thanks, I'll change that

Comment: "beny23 True, will edit :)

Comment: @beny23 I'll update the post again

Comment: Consider using `String.format( "file:///path/to/%d.mp3", numSeq );` and convert numSeq to an integer.

Comment: How about the output of `ls -l /Users/user/Desktop/FinishedPhone/99.mp3`?

Comment: @Yakattak: Could you change to `System.out.println("[" + soundLoc + "]");` and show the console output when trying `111`?

Comment: Some code from SoundPlayer would be useful too, as its the class that actually instantiates the `File` object.

Comment: If you remove the scheme file:// in front of the path, does it still work?

Comment: @Dimitri no, it throws a no protocol exception

Comment: Did you check after this line File file = new File(soundLoc); whether the file exist or not? I think your problem is there

Comment: @FestusTamakloe it says false no matter what for some reason.

Comment: @DaveJarvis it hangs when I use parseInt :/ unfortunately these numbers are coming from an Arduino serial message, so they come in as strings.

Comment: Is something holding onto those files?  From the docs of FileInputStream: _Throws:
FileNotFoundException - if the file does not exist, is a directory rather than a regular file, or for some other reason cannot be opened for reading._  How about ``lsof|grep 100.mp3``?

Comment: Ok. your numSeq has problem. Try to trim it like this return "file:///Users/user/Desktop/FinishedPhone/" + numSeq.trim() + ".mp3"

Comment: @ChrisKnight it returns nothing

Comment: @FestusTamakloe it worked! thank you! If you submit it as an answer I'll check it off!

Comment: You're welcome. I just submit it as answer. Thanks

Comment: @Yakattak: The moral of the story is to always surround debugging output with delimiters to avoid missing leading or trailing spaces:  `System.out.println("[" + soundLoc+ "]")` would have shown the problem quickly...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your numSeq has problem. Try to trim it like this

```
 return "file:///Users/user/Desktop/FinishedPhone/" + numSeq.trim() + ".mp3
```

Answer (score -1):

Well, I guess the problem come with the fact that you are using `file://` scheme in front the path. I don't know exactly how the `File(String pathname)` behaves when using this scheme.
The File class takes many constructors and particuly this one `File(URI uri)` whose Javadoc says :

> Creates a new File instance by converting the given file: URI into an abstract pathname.

So, in my opinion, you should use this constructor instead of the previous one. Let me show you some code that proves what I say :

```
    public class FileTest {

    /**
     * @param args
     * @throws URISyntaxException 
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws URISyntaxException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String pathWithNoScheme = "/home/dimitri/workspace/Coursera/collinear/input6.txt";
        String pathWithScheme = "file://" + pathWithNoScheme;
        URI uri = new URI(pathWithScheme);


        File fileWithNoScheme = new File(pathWithNoScheme);
        System.out.println(fileWithNoScheme.canRead()); //returns true

        File fileWithScheme = new File(uri);
        System.out.println(fileWithScheme.canRead()); //returns true

        fileWithNoScheme = new File(pathWithScheme);
        System.out.println(fileWithNoScheme.canRead()); //returns false

    }

}
```

As you see the when passing a `file://` scheme to the `File(String pathName)` constructor,  it returns false but when I pass it to an URI, it returns true.

So change `findSoundFile` to return an `URI` instead of a String or wrapped the return value of this method to an URI