# FileNotFoundException: Playing an mp3 file with Java/Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, nullpointerexception, mp3, libraries

I am trying to play an mp3 using an external mp3 library and everything is fine until it comes to finding the file.

I have imported the file into eclipse as seen in the below image.
[image: My workspace]

And here is my error:

```
enProblem playing file mpthreetest.mp3
java.io.FileNotFoundException: mpthreetest.mp3 (The system cannot find the file   specified)
java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: If you posted more code it would be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot find your file because you're trying to access it by a relative path. But probably you aren't considering that a package, at runtime, is NOT a directory.

So, if you try to look for a file by new File("myfile") the JVM assume you're starting from the "root" of your application (usually the working dir).

To solve this situation you can put the mp3 file in root package or by referring to it via absolute path.

Answer (score 1):

Check the current execution dir: `new java.io.File(".").getAbsolutePath()` will tell you.

Comment: I have the path and it will still not find the file.

Comment: What does it mean? Are you now using the absolute path of the mp3?

Comment: I think this is not possibile :) Anyway, a better and portable approach is reading it from the classloader. The MP3 class can read from an InputStream? If so, InputStream is = getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("com/cephon/game/mpthreetest.mp3").

Comment: if with the absolute path does not work, check the path separator (/ or \\ ), or spaces in the path, or if the user has permissions to read the file.

Comment: BTW, have you checked this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15350392/filenotfoundexception-the-file-exists-java?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

Try giving the absolute path of the file and see if that works.